# How can I collect fee in every transaction in Ethereum private Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-clique

I'm going to deploy a new chain but can I collect fee from every transaction happen in this chain and the fee will be automatically credited in a account without creating any exchange to collect fee.

Comment: I know only miners can get fee but I want to charge extra

Comment: Such feature isn't part of the geth client, so if you need that feature you'll have to modify the source code.